# First Time Intorduction Screen with Animation

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen, horizontalscrollview

I am looking for animation like this in iPhone [DRDynamicSlideShow github](https://github.com/Dromaguirre/DRDynamicSlideShow).

for my one time introduction screen in android.

I started with (snapping/paging) HorizontalScrollView.

Paging HorizontalScrollView is working,

but unable to have animation effect on views from one page to another on swipe of finger as in above github iPhone example.

unable to find similar animation example tutorial  for android.

any help highly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [YahooNewsOnboarding](https://github.com/rahulrj/YahooNewsOnboarding) library, it looks awesome and I guess it is what you need actually.

Comment: Thanks...for answer.really i need this one. But  I did it by my self.. with lots of pain... :)